How to maintain dependencies shared among microservices?
There is a dependency jar containing tons of service classes mostly used to retrieve data from database, and this jar is used among several different micro services in one cluster.
There is a big problem in such architecture: once a new method is added to any of the service class in the dependency jar, it is next to impossible to change the method signature, since the method is used already by several microservices. This causes big maintenance cost on those service classes
Question: how to reduce the maintenance cost on the shared service jar? is there better alternative to share those service dependency jar among the microservices?

The question is ok (and you are not the only one who had issues with such a design), but it is missing information on the organization maintaining this system. Are their individual teams for maintaining each service? Is there a separate team for the shared service? How independent are these teams organized? Or is all in the hand of one small team, so changes to the system can be propagated easily even when they affect different services? I recommend to add this information by editong the question.

Obvious solution: export the jar's API as another microservice. (I'm joking, but this is actually a serious criticism of microservice nonsense)

This is not a specific problem to microservices. This is something you'll see with any library used by many people. It may be prudent to see how big libraries (like Spring and even Java itself) handle this problem.

@DocBrown organization maintaining this system is a product development department consisting of several scrum teams. One maintains the module services in a monolith, other teams maintains their own microservices using those services

Similar Q on StackOverflow: Sharing code and schema between microservices

@pjc50: I believe that is indeed what microservice proponents do (splitting off a new service) - so not everyone thinks that's a joke...

Without knowing some more specifics, it's hard to speculate on particular solutions. Changing method signatures in a Jar is going to cause this type of situation whether you use microservices or not; it's simply more frequent in microservices.

I have never used it myself, but OpenRewrite is a solution for performing upgrades of code automatically. But more importantly: if an API is no stable, it should probably not be part of a shared library (yet). Also each microservice should have its own database, and access other functional domains through other microservices and not their database. Then you can have a thin, stable client library for the microservice (or just use Swagger).

Combine the dependency and the cluster of micro-services into one monolith.
Adopting microservices should be about enabling independent development and deployment of individual parts, reducing interdependancies of work, and solving a problem that can't be solved in any other reasonable way.
It sounds like you aren't getting these benefits, since work on any one service probably often requires changes to that dependency. And since presumably the database is shared between the different microservices, all services will have to have a relatively recent version of the dependency at all times, as an old version would assume a database structure that no longer exists and not work.
So effectively you have to deploy the various services in near lockstep.
Combining them into a monolith would mean you deploy them exactly in lockstep, with a single command that deploys all of them together, and the possibility to easily run tests and static analysis in advance on each version of the monolith well before deploying it to production.
Changing a method signature at the method declaration and all method usages can then be done in a single commit, and often with an automatic refactoring command in an IDE.
(I don't know the OP's organization, so this answer may or may not be right for them, but I present it as an option to be considered and voted on)

This is what I was thinking as well, however I don't know if combining these services constitutes a monolith. Don't confuse the word "micro" in microservices with "a tiny application." But there is a line where you cross into monolith territory.

@GregBurghardt That's true, it might just make a bigger microservice. I think microservice and monolith architectures are two ends of a spectrum. If this doesn't make a monolith then it would at least move the OP's org a little in that direction.

It's funny, because my first thought was that this organization tried splitting a monolith into microservices, and bringing it back towards a monolith might be good until they can properly separate things.

Rather than a monolith, make it a monorepo - which is a monolith with good management instrumentation that prevents dependency hell, does actual incremental build and deployment, plus a bunch of other good stuff. Really good intro: https://monorepo.tools

@Jonathan It might be worth expanding your comment into a full answer.

Exported methods should be part of a stable API, which means that you never change the signature of a method once it is published, unless you create a new major version of the library.
If you use the semantic versioning terminology, addition of new backward compatible functionality, such as adding a new method, increases the minor version number when you publish that version. Clients of your library will normally specify which minimum minor version of a fixed major version they will need, and that's enough. They will continue to work with newer versions, as long as you keep the promise given by the semantic versioning rules.
If you make breaking changes to your library (such as removing previously exported methods, or changing signatures, or changing names), you need to create a new major version. Since old clients of your library will not know about this version, you will need to provide and maintain the latest minor version of that old version as long as those clients have not been migrated to the new version. This is normal, and the maintenance overhead for the old version should be minimal (it does not get any functional enhancements, you would just patch critical bugs, creating patch releases).

I've thought so too, but Python, Java and many popular libraries deprecate stuff all the time. There is an established procedure for that and Python will never again increase major version.

I guess what I'm seeing is that Semver is dying.

That's indeed conceivable, as the approach may be too radical for many situations. A softened procedure (deprecate stuff and remove some versions later) may be acceptable in many cases. You just want to avoid creating pressure on all users of your library to update in lockstep just because some interface changed a little.

@Basilevs Python is a bit of a special case, because we're still traumatized from the last major version upgrade. And Java never followed SemVer in the first place—every release is either a bugfix or a new major version.

@Basilevs: Semver doesn't particularly inhibit deprecation. All it really preaches is to not inherently have the release of a new endpoint also entail the deprecation of the old endpoint (which is what inherently happens when you apply breaking changes to the existing endpoint). Semver gets you to create new endpoints when they have breaking changes, and while it does include advice on not deprecating previous endpoints at least until a reasonable grace period has elapsed since the release of the new endpoint, it makes no statements about never deprecating old endpoints.

"you never change the signature of a method once it is published" This may be somewhat of a nitpick but I'd rephrase this to not introducing breaking changes. Extending the signature in a way that does not break the old usage (e.g. upgrading an int to a double, or adding an optional param) don't break existing consumers and don't cause issues. Also, while an edge case, critical bugfixes are allowed to make breaking changes if and only if the endpoint was flawed on release to the point of being unworkable (at which point you're not breaking it, since it wasn't working in the first place).

@Flater semver does inhibit deprecation. Clients are unwilling to migrate to a new major, knowing it is backward incompatible. Services are therefore unwilling to bump major. This leads to accumulation of deprecated APIs. The large pool of APIs to remove further reduces client's will to upgrade. This is a vicious cycle witch results in either death by cruft (users  can no longer tolerate the API that can't improve) or death by bump (most clients stay on previous major).
Other policies tend to not to group a lot of deprecations, reducing the impact.

@Flater Widening a param type is not a breaking change on a final class, but it is a breaking change if consumers may have extend your class or implemented your interface.

Does it count as breaking if users need to recompile? Languages like Java store the exact signature being called in compiled code, since they allow overloading.

@Basilevs "Clients tend to then do X" != "The guideline prescribes this as the correct approach". As per semver.org: "Deprecating existing functionality is a normal part of software development and is often required to make forward progress. [..] Before you completely remove the functionality in a new major release there should be at least one minor release that contains the deprecation so that users can smoothly transition to the new API." Service owners should not be bulled into staying with the same major version just because clients don't want to upgrade. [..]

@Flater sue them!

@Basilevs: [..] The clients don't own the product, for starters. Also, refusing to bump majors or deprecate existing functionality enables clients to stick with stale versions. Service owners should be charting their own development, marking that progress with minor/major version upgrades as appropriate, and deprecate old versions when they're outside of the owners' support range (e.g. too different from the newer product, too many inherent support issues, security issues, ...)

On a more serious note, this is just usual business, a "market" of sorts - clients just chose better service and the compatibility is an important part of service quality.

@Basilevs: Sure, needing customer sign-on is a fact of life for services that operate in a buyer's market. I agree with you there. But semver is not a marketing strategy and you shouldn't judge the guideline by decisions made for ulterior reasons which are unrelated to the guideline's content. Semver itself does not inhibit deprecation. Developers (who also use semver) might inhibit deprecation due to their customer's demains. Semver is a strawman in all of this.

@Flater oh, they are related - the semver just forces all clients to take responsibility for integration of a breaking change they are not interested in. Clients do not like sharing responsibility, they expect a carefully managed upgrade plan that does not affect them in particular. Most deprecations are not heavily used after all, and clients just like to hope that they would be fine upgrading to a next calendar version (for example). Whereas if they upgrade major, they would not be even able to complain about breaking changes.

@Basilevs: I get the feeling you misunderstand semver. Semver does the opposite of forcing the client's hand. A non-semver service which introduces a breaking change would forcefully overwrite the old way into the new one, forcing all clients into immediate action. A semver service would introduce this breaking change on an alternate path, providing the option to stick with the old way for as long as it would not be deprecated, allowing clients to upgrade to the new version at their own pace. [..]

@Basilevs [..] That is the polar opposite of "semver just forces all clients to take responsibility for integration of a breaking change" as you claim. It seems like you think that applying semver somehow increases the amount of breaking changes that get introduced (as per your mention of "a carefully managed upgrade plan that does not affect them in particular"). This is not the case. Semver does not increase the breakage, it tells you to contain the breakage (that was already going to happen), specifically to avoid having to force the client's hand on a schedule that's not their own.

@Basilevs: My suspicion is that you're judging the overall guideline by your firsthand (or secondhand) experience with a dev team that exhibited flaws with their versioning and deprecation methodology that were problematic for their clients; but the problems you are describing are in actual fact not caused by semver's guideline, just by developers badly applying it (and potentially pointing at semver as the supposed justification for their bad decisions).

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

There really is no easy way to resolve this. The microservices are coupled at a much deeper layer than they should be. Reducing the maintenance cost means properly decoupling these things so that microservices are coupled to each other via web API endpoints or message brokers. You and your organization will need to reorient your perspective on code reuse.
Any change to a monolith requires the whole monolith to be deployed. As a result, it becomes very easy to couple code between modules in a monolith. Even loosely coupled code changes require the whole thing to be packaged, retested, and deployed. Microservices change the economics of coupling because coordinated deployments for multiple services are more costly in time and effort — the beating heart of your question. While shared libraries of code spanning wide swaths of behavior can be viable for a monolith architecture, microservices become even more complicated.
Instead of reusing code at a lower abstraction, for example sharing business classes or service classes, one entire microservice becomes the minimum unit of behavior that gets reused.
Get rid of the shared library.
This thing is a monolith disguised as a dependency.
The boundary of a microservice is defined by the business functions it serves, and the data for which the microservice should be considered the single source of truth. A microservice should wholly own a business process and the necessary data to perform that business process independently of other microservices. It's ok to copy data to other services, as long as those other services all agree on which one acts as the single source of truth for some particular data.
If one service needs to implement behavior owned by another service, then call the other service. Delegate that behavior to the service that owns that business process. Doing this allows you to remove the monolith service layer that leaves these services tangled and intertwined.
Of course, this is a tone deaf answer if your organization can't or is unwilling to support this separation. If this common dependency cannot be eliminated, then I wouldn't consider the ecosystem to be a microservices architecture. You will be stuck with versioned APIs or combining these microservices together. bdsl mentions this in their answer, but you aren't necessarily making a "monolith microservice". Remember the main characteristics of a microservice are that it is independently deployable and scalable. If you can combine these services and achieve that level of autonomy, you can still call it a microservice. It just might be a big one, that's all.
It's too bad that microservice has the word "micro" in it. Too often people equate microservices with tiny applications, and that is not the main characteristic. Smaller applications are a side effect of separating main lines of business functions into independently deployable and scalable units. The independently deployable and scalable unit becomes the unit of code reuse within your organization. Deeper levels of reuse often land you precisely where you are right now.

"so that microservices are coupled to each other via web API endpoints or message brokers." - I don't think it matters much whether the services are coupled by web APIs, message formats, SQL schemas, or Java APIs. The real work in decoupling this mess is redefining the service boundaries.

TL;DR: Change the signature and don't upgrade until ready.
I am, actually, in a similar situation at work, and it's an architecture I chose. In order to protect IP, our codebases are organized in the following way:

A "public" codebase, to which every developer gets access to, which define common functionality, communication protocols, client libraries, etc... for all applications.
Many "need-to-know" codebases, which are built atop the previous one.

Any change to the API of the public codebase requires a bit of integration work in the other codebases, and that's completely fine by us.
How it works:

Dependency by commit, not version. Every release is a potentially breaking change, so no SemVer is used.
Eager upgrade to affected applications in case of bugs.
Lazy (deferred) upgrade to affected applications in case of functionality change/improvement; typically until the application actually needs to be changed for other reasons.

It does require commitment, and it does mean that sometimes you'd want to make a quick change to core functionality for an application that hasn't been upgraded in a while, and must first wade through unrelated integration changes.
It's a trade-off we accept so far, in exchange for the productivity we get out of the setup.

I think there are two main ways to think about this and how to deal with it.
One is that when you have a shared library in your code base, you need to really think about managing it the way an open-source library would be managed. It makes no sense to me to pretend like this is an unsolvable problem. Think about all the libraries that you use in a given application and all the other applications that use those libraries as well. We don't even know the authors and the other users in the vast majority of these cases. Building a shared library that is used and maintained by your own team has a lot of the same challenges but is a much simpler problem to solve. No professional developer would seriously suggest writing an entire application without any external dependencies. Suggesting that building and maintaining a shared lib on a much smaller scope is an intractable problem is just as ridiculous. Hans-Martin Mosner's answer has some practical advice relating to this. I've seen teams that cannot seem to move beyond copy-paste-modify approaches but don't let anyone convince you that is a sophisticated way to go about things.
The other thought is, if you are thinking of microservices as arbitrarily splitting up every endpoint/operation, perhaps consider a more (IMO) reasonable idea of microservices where you divide groups of related capabilities into mini-monoliths. That is, components of your design which operate on the same databases and/or are otherwise inherently intertwined with each other should be thought of as part of a single application, regardless of whether they are deployed independently. There are a lot of nonpragmatic recommendations in microservice literature which treat the benefits of independent deployment as inherently worth the costs. In many cases, this results in a lot of complication for little or no benefit. At this point, I think it's non-controversial to assert that blind adherence to a naive microservices model has resulted in a lot of poorly executed solutions and project failures.

Put all your code - services+libraries - in a monorepo
You've hit the classical problems with micro services. A better way would be to manage your project as a monorepo - a single repo, but managed with monorepo instrumentation so you don't problems associated with a less-well-managed monolith - dependency hell and others.
I found this site extremely well-written in describing the problem and suggested solutions: https://monorepo.tools
We use NX - one of the proposed monorep management tools - and it works great.
